# Loading a csv file with no header on my Colab by Pandas read_csv and Numpy loadtxt gave me a different results

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv, google-colaboratory

[This is the image of the error on my Colab when I used pd.dtye to pd_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHplE.png)
[This is the image of the error on my Colab when I used np.dtye to pd_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGdwP.png)
I have loaded one csv file to my Colab note by two diffrent way. By pd.read_csv() and np.loadtxt(). And I have assigned these two in nd_data and pd_data ,repectively. After that I printed the shape of each data. At this point I've got two diffrent shape even though I loaded the same csv file.
My question is why I've got two diffrent shape by loading the same data.

[this is the link to ThoraricSurgery.csv file which I've used.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ggg8ARpXveOlNNklDP__4Uv69qF3K7b7/view?usp=sharing)

'''
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import pandas as pd

pd_data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/딥러닝과실습1/ThoraricSurgery.csv')
print(pd_data.shape)
print(type(pd_data))

import numpy as np

nd_data = np.loadtxt('/content/drive/MyDrive/딥러닝과실습1/ThoraricSurgery.csv', delimiter=",")
print(nd_data.shape)
print(type(nd_data))[this is the mentioned result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy9aL.png)
'''

Comment: `dtype` tells us more than the `type`.  Did you look at either result?  Not just the shape.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't know about the existence of dtype.  So I refered [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) this documnet and tried to use np.dtype on my Colab.  And the type error has occurred. Specifically :    "Cannot interpret '     293  1   3.8   2.8  0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  12  0.6  0.7  0.8  1.1  \ " But it says "[469 rows x 18 columns]' as a data type".

Comment: @hpaulj This is the current situation T_T  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGdwP.png    https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHplE.png

Comment: [link to solved ipynb file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IGc5pIQYWQ6Tz0VO1bXwcHvNxDnjeS3a?usp=sharing) After further research I figured it out. @hpaulj thank you for your comment.

Comment: I should have deduced that the csv was just numbers, since the `loadtxt` didn't raise an error, so `dtype` wasn't an issue.  Your initial difference was the result of `pandas` treating the first line as header, while `loadtxt` does not (as a default).  Still, it's good to learn how to identify the `dtype(s)` of an array or dataframe.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree that it's a good thing to learn. Thanks.